# Keras ImageDataGenerator flow class indices for sparse and categorical classes

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For keras's `ImageDataGenerator` `flow_*` methods, it requires a stringified version of class indices for categorical and sparse `class_mode`. I have class labels that look like `['0','1',...,'10','11',...]` and an unfortunate consequence is that Keras indexes these in string-alphabetical order:

For example:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=0,
        width_shift_range=0,
        height_shift_range=0,
        rescale=None,
        shear_range=0,
        zoom_range=0,
        horizontal_flip=False,
        preprocessing_function=preprocessor,
        fill_mode='nearest')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=dfTest,
    directory=None,
    x_col="filePath",
    y_col="ycat",
    target_size=SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='sparse',
    shuffle=False)

    print(test_generator.class_indices)
```

gives:

```
{'0': 0,
 '1': 1,
 '10': 2,
 '11': 3,
 ...,
 '2': 12,
 '20': 13,
 '21': 14,
 '22': 15,
 '3': 16,
 '4': 17,
 '5': 18,
 '6': 19,
 '7': 20,
 '8': 21,
 '9': 22}
```

Ideally I'd like to see:

```
{'0': 0,
 '1': 1,
 '2': 2,

 ...,
 }
```

I thought about manually changing `test_generator.class_indices` but I'm not sure that's safe to do as after initialization, the generator has pre-calculated the class labels of the dataset.

Is there a nice solution to this without rewriting the `flow_*` method?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Did you find a nice solution?

Comment: @Tullhead: see answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set as per your requirement using `classes` argument. But currently `classes` argument is working for `flow_from_directory` but not working as expected in `flow_from_dataframe`. I can see a ticket open for this in keras [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/pull/270). It should be fixed in upcoming versions of tensorflow.

**flow_from_directory Example:** Here class_indices will be {'dogs': 0, 'cats': 1} instead of {'cats': 0, 'dogs': 1}.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs.zip', origin=_URL, extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'cats_and_dogs_filtered')

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')  # directory with our training cat pictures
train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')  # directory with our training dog pictures
validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')  # directory with our validation cat pictures
validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')  # directory with our validation dog pictures

num_cats_tr = len(os.listdir(train_cats_dir))
num_dogs_tr = len(os.listdir(train_dogs_dir))

num_cats_val = len(os.listdir(validation_cats_dir))
num_dogs_val = len(os.listdir(validation_dogs_dir))

total_train = num_cats_tr + num_dogs_tr
total_val = num_cats_val + num_dogs_val

batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='binary',
                                                           classes = ['dogs','cats'])

print(train_data_gen.class_indices)
```

**Output -**

```
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
{'dogs': 0, 'cats': 1}
```

**Not working in flow_from_dataframe:** Seems like a bug and should be fixed as per the ticket soon. In the meanwhile you can fix it by replacing your labels to alphabets like '0' as 'a', '1' as 'b' OR modify the code to use `flow_from_directory`, but again a over head task.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import pandas as pd

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def append_ext(fn):
    return fn+".png"

traindf = pd.read_csv("/content/trainLabels.csv",dtype=str)

traindf["id"]=traindf["id"].apply(append_ext)

datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split=0.25)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                            dataframe=traindf,
                            directory="/content/train/",
                            x_col="id",
                            y_col="label",
                            subset="training",
                            batch_size=32,
                            seed=42,
                            shuffle=True,
                            class_mode="categorical",
                            target_size=(32,32),
                            classes=['truck', 'ship', 'horse', 'frog', 'dog', 'deer', 'cat', 'bird', 'automobile', 'airplane'])

print(train_generator.class_indices)
```

**Output -** Still working in alphanumeric manner.

```
Found 37500 validated image filenames belonging to 10 classes.
{'airplane': 0, 'automobile': 1, 'bird': 2, 'cat': 3, 'deer': 4, 'dog': 5, 'frog': 6, 'horse': 7, 'ship': 8, 'truck': 9}
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.